# Stop the Collide Values and respawn the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this scene there are two `boxes` when user press `space` key `box1` collide with other box then score increment. But the problem which i faces, one is when `box1` collide with other box then `box1` drops on the ground and it's position values doesn't stop. Second is when score increment how to respawn that box1 again.

```
public class box1 : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rigid;

    void Start () {

        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        rigid.isKinematic = true;

    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            rigid.isKinematic = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Box 2:

```
public class boxer2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public int timeshit;
    public Text texter;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        timeshit = 0;

        texter.text = "Score Fall : " + timeshit;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
        timeshit++;
        texter.text = "Score Fall : " + timeshit;

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

New Code Updated :

```
public class boxer2 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject boxObj;
    public int timeshit;
    public Text texter;

    void Start () {
        timeshit = 0;

        texter.text = "Score Fall : " + timeshit;
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        timeshit++;
        texter.text = "Score Fall : " + timeshit;
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Destroy(col.gameObject,0.5f);
        }
        Instantiate(boxObj, new Vector3(0.04f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);

    }

    }
```

Comment: Should old box1 be destroyed before another box1 spawned? Do you want to achieve stop old box1 and spawn new box1 both? or one of the choices?

Comment: @burakKarasoy destroy old box1 and spawn new box1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Declare a Public GameObject boxObj;//Don't forget to assign your box's prefab
         void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
            timeshit++;
            texter.text = "Score Fall : " + timeshit;
            Destroy(col.gameObject,0.1f); 
        //  if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {//add a tag to your box and check it before destroying a gameObject
        //  Destroy(col.gameObject,0.1f);
        //  }


         Instantiate(boxObj, new Vector3(x?F, y?, z?), Quaternion.identity);
         // x,y,z are your desired positions

        }
```

also check this links 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreateDestroyObjects.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

And you need to assign tour box object's reference from prefab not from hierarchy because when the object in hierarchy destroyed, it will work for first time, but second attempt the object can not be founded. You should follow thre green arrow in your situation.
[image]

Comment: when object second time destroy then error come The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Comment: Did you add something from col in new Vector3(positions) add your last updated code.

Comment: i updated my answer with new code and added tag Player on box1 and put box1 GameObject in box2 variable but the error still same `The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it`

Comment: @tim yes i will open pc in a few hours